# .NET GC stuck on JNI call from finalizer()

Tags: java, .net, java-native-interface, clr

I have a .NET application that is using JNI to call Java code. On the .NET finalizer we call a JNI call to clean the connected resource on Java. But from time to time this JNI gets stuck.
This as expected stuck the all .NET process and never releases.

Bellow you can see the thread dump we got from .NET:

NET Call Stack 
Function

```
.JNIEnv_.NewByteArray(JNIEnv_*, Int32) 
Bridge.NetToJava.JVMBridge.ExecutePBSCommand(Byte[], Int32, Byte[])
Bridge.Core.Internal.Pbs.Commands.PbsDispatcher.Execute(Bridge.Core.Internal.Pbs.PbsOutputStream, Bridge.Core.Internal.DispatcherObjectProxy) 
Bridge.Core.Internal.Pbs.Commands.PbsCommandsBundle.ExecuteGenericDestructCommand(Byte, Int64, Boolean) 
Bridge.Core.Internal.DispatcherObjectProxy.Dispose(Boolean) 
Bridge.Core.Internal.Transaction.Dispose(Boolean) 
Bridge.Core.Internal.DispatcherObjectProxy.Finalize()
```

Full Call Stack 
Function

```
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet 
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+c 
kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+ac 
kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+12 
jvm!JVM_FindSignal+5cc49 
jvm!JVM_FindSignal+4d0be 
jvm!JVM_FindSignal+4d5fa 
jvm!JVM_FindSignal+beb8e 
jvm+115b 
jvm!JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs+1d26 
Bridge_NetToJava+1220 
clr!MethodTable::SetObjCreateDelegate+bd 
clr!MethodTable::CallFinalizer+ca 
clr!SVR::CallFinalizer+a7 
clr!WKS::GCHeap::TraceGCSegments+239 
clr!WKS::GCHeap::TraceGCSegments+415 
clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+cd 
clr!Thread::DoExtraWorkForFinalizer+114 
clr!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+101 
clr!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+399 
clr!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+35 
clr!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+f 
clr!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+10c 
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4b 
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34
```

Comment: In Java its considered a bad idea to use finalizers so using one from .NET to call JNI to call Java doesn't sound like a great idea. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't find a question I won't post a formal answer here but rather tell a story about something similar I underwent sometimes:

We created C ojects via JNI, that were backed by java object, and we decided to clean the C objects within the finalize method. However, we envisioned deadlocks, as the finalize is called from a non-application thread, the garbage-collector. As the entire wolrd is stopped while collecting the garbage, whenever the finalizer meets a lock it's immediately a dead lock. Thus we decided to use a java mechnism called phantom references. It's possible to bind a number to each of these 'references' (the C pointer) and then the VM removes an referenced object it puts such an reference into a queue. And one can pull this data whenever appropriate and remove the C object.

I think at least your problem is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in our case this is the opposite around. We create Java objects from .NET and we want to clean the Java objects when the .NET objects are collected.

Comment: I'm aware of this. If .net doesn't provide a similar mechanism you could still queue your ids in the finalize method. What would bring you around this critical issue.

Comment: But the thread that will take the items from this queue and do the same dispose mechanism can hang exactly in the same location and I'll have a hanged thread. Which I cannot even abort since it is running in native code. Unless you think the GC is hanged because it is causing a deadlock since it calls the native code and a different thread will not hang?

Comment: I think the GC thread hangs, once it trys to obtain an application lock. As all application threads are stopped the locked can never be released. If the same mechansim hits the same lock in an application thread the other thread continues running and releases the lock... In GC one of the involved locks is the big fat stop the world lock. Getting rit of this is the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea whether .NET finalizers are equally bad idea to Java finalizers, but using a potentially (dead)locking code (i see Win32 condition call at the very bottom) from anything like finalizer (regardless of the platform) is definitely a bad idea. You need to clean your native code of any potential locking, or have an emergency brake timeout at the level of .NET

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it?
We create Java objects from .NET and we want to clean the Java objects when the .NET objects are collected

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you clean the Java objects exactly at the same time when you collect the .NET objects? Is there any danger that the orphaned Java objects will be attempted to be used when the .NET counterparts are already collected? Can't you decouple the cleaning in Java from .NET? Do it at different time?